# new category appears near home page tite, why?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I installed PrestaShop 1.7.1.2 and I added many categories, one of them appears on the top menu of the front page, only a specific one of them. I don't know why, I didn't add any products to it.

you can see it by browsing to `prestashop.tux-in.com` and near the `CLASSIC` title which is a link to the homepage, `DIFFERENT HOLDERS` is also shown there which is an empty category. what am I missing? why is this category alone is shown there?

how can I remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it coming from top horizontal menu module, please check it in admin under module section  and remove it.